# Best match not found by ADL after point of instantiation. Is this UB?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup, dependent-name

Consider the following code, in which the location of the overloads of `f` causes some non-intuitive behaviour. The code compiles with no warnings in both Clang 3.4.1 and gcc 4.8.

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    static const int value = sizeof(f(T()));
};

struct B
{
};

struct D : B
{
};

char f(B);

// instantiates A<D>, unqualified name lookup finds f(B) via ADL
static_assert(A<D>::value == sizeof(f(B())), ""); // passes

long f(D); // but wait, f(D) would be a better match!

// A<D> is already instantiated, f(D) is not found
static_assert(A<D>::value == sizeof(f(B())), ""); // passes
```

The C++11 standard suggests that the above code invokes undefined behaviour:

> [temp.dep.candidate]
>
> For a function call that depends on a template parameter, the candidate functions are found using the usual
>   lookup rules except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup or qualified name lookup, only
>     function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces, only function declarations found in
>     either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.
>
> **If the function name is an unqualified-id and the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had
>   the lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with external linkage
>   introduced in those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the
>   template definition and template instantiation contexts, then the program has undefined behavior.**

Does the above code invoke this specific undefined behaviour? Could a high-quality implementation be expected to report a warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the above code invoke this specific undefined behaviour?

Yes. [temp.point]/7:

> The instantiation context of an expression that depends on the
>   template arguments is **the set of declarations with external linkage
>   declared prior to the point of instantiation of the template
>   specialization in the same translation unit**.

The point of instantiation is right after the first `static_assert`-declaration:

> For […] a specialization for a […] static data member of a class
>   template, if the specialization is implicitly instantiated because it
>   is referenced from within another template specialization […].
>   **Otherwise, the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that
>   refers to the specialization.**

So there would indeed be a better match if we would have considered the second function declaration - which we couldn't, since it's declared after the point of instantiation of `A<D>::value`. According to the rule you quoted the code induces undefined behavior. 
The rule is basically extending the ODR to dependent name lookup in templates.

> Could a high-quality implementation be expected to report a warning?

I wouldn't. Consider also that undefined behavior reaches back to compile time; The compiler is allowed but not required to issue a warning or error message if the code induces UB. Do not expect compilers to always point out illegal code.

Comment: I guess 'expect' is too strong, but it would certainly be desirable to get a warning!